# Integrating serial communication in wx GUI

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, pyserial, wxwidgets

```
  def updateV(self, event):
    """"""
    global v
    v=random.uniform(1,10)
    print('battery voltage =')
    print(v)
    if v>3:
        self.labelOne.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        self.labelOne.SetLabel('Battery Voltage : ' + str(v))


    else:
        self.labelOne.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.labelOne.SetLabel('Battery Voltage : ' + str(v))


    self.Refresh()
```

this is a function in my wxpython GUI which i use for generating random values.I have added this function in my panel class of the GUI. I have put a wx.Bind function that assigns a timer value to it and refreshes it regularly for value change regularly.

Now the GUI needs to have serial communication as I need to get sensor values and get them input in my GUI screen. So i found this code for serially inputing the value:

```
 def updateV(self, event):
    """"""
    global v
    v=ser.readline()
    print v
    if v>3:
        self.labelOne.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        self.labelOne.SetLabel('Battery Voltage : ' + str(v))


    else:
        self.labelOne.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.labelOne.SetLabel('Battery Voltage : ' + str(v))


    self.Refresh()
```

I then went it the **init** part of the panel class and added this code:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0)
```

On running the GUI, the value doesnt appear nor does it print it on the GUI. I know I am doing a big mistake here. Anyways the values right now come through an arduino uno connected to a XBEE shield which receives 1-20 values through another arduino conencted to a XBEE shield. By the way, random variables are generated properly and are printed in the GUI so there is'nt any proble with the function. 
I need a way for python to read the value serially and assign it to a variable such that I can print the value I get in my GUI screen. 
PS: I used the same serial code to properly get 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 value on the command screen of python module.

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0)

while 1:
    v=ser.readline()
    print v
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am trying to get used to python, but these small things hinder my progress.. I am new to python, please bear with me!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is essentially that reading the serial interface in the `while` loop with `ser.readline()` as in your last example (*EDIT1*: and also when polling with a `wx.Timer` event) will block the GUI when it is waiting for data on the serial interface. *Calling the* `app.MainLoop()` *will loop the wxPython event system. However, the only thing your GUI example will do is blocking at `ser.readline()`. As soon some data comes it will continue in the `updateV` method. But because the next timer event is waiting already, it will run to `ser.readline()` and block there again and preventing any GUI updates.*

Did you try out the [wxTerminal](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/pyserial/code/trunk/pyserial/examples/) example in the pyserial package?

It shows how to spin of a thread which will do the reading and sending a user-defined `SerialRxEvent` so that everything is thread-safe.

You also should read [LongRunningTasks in the wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) to get an idea how to use threads for long running/blocking tasks in wxPython and communicate back to the main GUI thread safely.

Comment: i never added a while loop in the GUI. I expected the mainloop() to do the same work as the while infinite loop, but it never works that way. Any way can I get serial communication in the GUI using the mainloop()?

Comment: Have your read (and understood) the examples I posted in my answer?

Comment: I  have read it but need more clarity in them. I am unable to associate how to use them in my GUI. I need more material I guess